# How to detect if a signal raises sharply or slowly?

Tags: signal-analysis, signal-power

so how can i detect if a signal raises sharply or not ? Are there easy solutions (i suppose there are) ?

the problem is that if a signal raises sharply, i need less data to not pollute the dataset and if the signal raises slowly then i need more data. But how to determine the number of data, without knowing if it's sharp or not?

Also I need to know if it raises sharply when i'm at the top of the curve, NOT afterwards (in realtime if you want)

thanks so much

here is two examples of signals
http://khaelis.com/downloads/screenshotSharp.jpg
http://khaelis.com/downloads/screenshotSlow.jpg

Jeff

Comment: I think you should add more information about the type of signal and what exactly is sharp and what not (what is the threshold between these states?). Some examples would be helpful too.

Comment: thank you for that answer. here is an example of a sharp signal, and here is an example of a slow signal (to filter). 
I was thinking maybe just look at the max slope of the past few bars ? (then the number of past bars doens't matter so much, i can look from a zero cross). http://khaelis.com/downloads/screenshotSharp.jpg   and   http://khaelis.com/downloads/screenshotSlow.jpg   (positiveness doesn't matter , sorry it's reversed)

Comment: Edit your question and add these examples. Additionally it sustains unclear what the boarder between slow and sharp is?

Comment: yes that's exactly my point. that's why i'm asking the questions. Maybe calculate the standart deviation bewteen all the past slopes (fropm a zero crossing?). a high standart deviation would means the difference between the slopes angle is high (what occurs in sharp signals) whereas if the STD DEV is low it means all the slopes are kinda the same. What do you think? That plus using the max slope

Comment: It is difficult to help you, as no one besides you has experience with the data.  How comparable or equal are all slow and sharpe slopes in general. We have no idea about the variability of your data. This information is missing

Comment: ok here is more data to show you. Of course the peak has to be high enough, but this data alone is not enough. I need to know if the signal rose sharply, from a low value or if the signal rose slowly http://khaelis.com/downloads/screenshotSharp2.jpg   in this picture i can see one valid signal only (near the end obviously) because some other rose sharply but were not high enough)

Comment: Look, there are so main details and questions about the characteristics ( the statistic) of your slopes and amplitudes, without these information it is difficult if not impossible to suggest any classification algorithms to distinguish between the scenarios

Comment: hmm i agree, but i'm not  sure what you want me to do for you, so you can direct me to the right tool ? i can do whatever you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you can calculate the derivate which is the rate of signal change. In discrete signals this is obtained (approximated) by:

$$x'[k] = x[k]-x[k-1]$$

(by other words, it's the difference between consecutive samples)

Comment: Yes, and thank you for your answer. But with the derivative (the slope) how can i differenciate between a sharp signal and a slow signal ? my idea would be to compare the max slope between signals, but this is looking at only ONE information, i think there would be a better way to determine the sharpness (if it rises fast or slow) thanks

Comment: If you integrate (sum up) the derivatives $x'[k]$ as described in the answer, you get a single figure that describes how strong the overall fluctuation is.

Comment: @Jeff you can define a threshold value for the derivative. Anything above this will be a sharp signal and below will be a slow signal.

Comment: hmm i think i will use weights in my calculation, because last values are more imporant than old values, right? so my idea is to make a weighted mean of the derivatives. I'm not sure how many bars ago i have to select : My idea would be to select the same "area" : meaning if there is a sharp tall signal, the area would be bigger so there would need less bars, but if the signal is low, then the area is smaller so i need more bars. What do you think?

Comment: The number of samples to consider depends on you sampling frequency and on what you consider to be a fast and a slow signal.